# How can I get the accessible name using win32 from c#?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, winapi, accessibility

How can I get the accessible name using win32 from c#? (the accessible name was set using the standard win form designer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Must use the Windows Automation API ( sounds strange for accesibility). Call

```
STDAPI AccessibleObjectFromWindow(
  __in   HWND hwnd,
  __in   DWORD dwObjectID,
  __in   REFIID riid,
  __out  void **ppvObject
);
```

with the REFIID IAccessible. Cast ppvObject into IAccessible and read the member get_accName.

[Windows Accessible API on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd373592%28VS.85%29.aspx)